# WSO2 api manager 2.6.0 Group API in Store How can have picture for thumbnail?

Tags: wso2, store, ibm-api-management

WSO2 api manager 2.6.0 Group API in Store How can have picture for thumbnail?
I use this document for group api in store:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Customizing+the+API+Store#CustomizingtheAPIStore-CategorizingandgroupingAPIs

and my collection name is :
aaa-group
and I create a collection with name :
aaa APIs-group

and use this name for picture:
thumbnail.png

BUT It's Don't Work!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps if you want to create groups and upload description and thumbnail image for your groups.

1. In the publisher, group the APIs by adding group names as tags. (according to your scenario API tag is **aaa APIs-group**). After doing this you will be able to see the group in the store.
2. Now log in to the carbon console (https://localhost:9443/carbon/) and do the steps mentioned in the docs(https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Customizing+the+API+Store#CustomizingtheAPIStore-CategorizingandgroupingAPIs) under the **Customizing the API group**.

Follow the extract steps mentioned in the docs.

In the last step, you need to name your thumbnail image as **thumbnail.png** and the description text file as **description.txt**  and upload those resources by clicking Add resource button and upload those 2 files. In the end, it should be like this. [image]

After that, you can see your uploaded image and description has applied to your group in the store